# Select the availability date for the first release of an iOS app

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

The first version of my iOS app got approved by Apple and is now in "Pending Developer Release" mode. I just set a "future release date" under iTunes Connect `Pricing` and got this message:

> You have selected an Available Date in the future. This will remove
>   your currently live version from the App Store until the new date.
>   Changing Available Date affects all versions of the application, both
>   Ready For Sale and In Review.

Will the automatic release date work or do I need to release the app manually? (I read on Stackoverflow that it may not work for the first release of an app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a date for release it will be release on that day, otherwise it will be in pending release until you push the release button...